# Ruby nokogiri selecting multiple elements

Tags: css, ruby

everybody, this is probably has a simple answer which I am overlooking (I am still learning).

I am trying to scrape data from a website, I am specific after particular p elements, which are nested inside different elements, this is what the nested elements look like.

```
#ctl00_body_divSearchResult > div:nth-child(5) > div.expandable-box-content.expanded > p:nth-child(2)

#ctl00_body_divSearchResult > div:nth-child(16) > div.expandable-box-content.expanded > p:nth-child(2)

#ctl00_body_divSearchResult > div:nth-child(27) > div.expandable-box-content.expanded > p:nth-child(2)

#ctl00_body_divSearchResult > div:nth-child(38) > div.expandable-box-content.expanded > p:nth-child(2)

#ctl00_body_divSearchResult > div:nth-child(49) > div.expandable-box-content.expanded > p:nth-child(2)
```

Here are five examples from the same page, the first div:nth-child has different numbers, but the rest is consistent.  I am after the individual p:nth-child(2) elements.

Using this code I can get the individual p elements,

```
numbers= agent.get(urlanzctr).css('#ctl00_body_divSearchResult > div:nth-child(5) > div.expandable-box-content > p:nth-child(2)').text
```

But I think it would be sloppy coding to go through and repeat this for each individual instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `agent.get(url).css(selector)` approach is right to return an array.

Looking at your selectors, they're all of this structure:

```
#ctl00_body_divSearchResult >
div:nth-child(N) >
div.expandable-box-content.expanded >
p:nth-child(2)
```

The only variable being the `N` in `div:nth-child`.

You have the values `5, 16, 27, 38, 49`

which is `11x + 5`

So you could do something like this

```
def make_selector(n)
  "#ctl00_body_divSearchResult > "         +
  "div:nth-child(#{n}) > "                 +
  "div.expandable-box-content.expanded > " +
  "p:nth-child(2)"
end

def get_matches(n)
  agent.get(url).css(make_selector(n))
end

starting_idx = 5
current_matches = get_matches(starting_idx)
all_matches = []

until current_matches.empty?
  all_matches.concat(current_matches)
  current_matches = get_matches(starting_idx + 11)
end

puts all_matches.length
```

You might also be able to skip out the intermediary selectors

i.e. maybe just `.expandable-box-content.exampled > p` would work; i have no idea what the page structure looks like.